# how to share a folder in django development server depyloment

Tags: python, django, ubuntu

I have created a virtual environment and installed latest django. Next I create a project. Now all i want to do is create a folder inside project directory to access its contents with browser when i do a development server deployment. How can i do this? do i need to create an app for this?

Comment: What's a "development server deployment"? What are you trying to access, and why?

Comment: the kind of deployment when you do simply python manage.py runserver after creating initial project accessible in browser through localhost:8000 . I want to put a  file inside my sharedfolder and want to be able access the file (e.g right click download ) from browser. reason - educational understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean, is to serve static files:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files

Basicly what you need to do is define 2 settings in your `settings.py`:

- STATICFILES_DIRS (which dir's do you want to serve these files from)
- STATIC_URL (what url do you want this folder to map to?)

for example:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    '/var/www/static/',
)

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

now you can access /var/www/static/image.jpg by visiting localhost:8000/static/image.jpg